# How can I move recycle bin from desktop into taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-8, recycle-bin

How can I remove the recycle bin icon from the desktop and move it into the taskbar?

It's really annoying to have this one icon in desktop -- I'd much rather have it on the taskbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarize the article [How to Pin the Recycle Bin to the Windows 7 Taskbar](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/6687-recycle-bin-pin-taskbar.html) :

1. Make sure the Recycle Bin is on the desktop.
2. Right click on the desktop and select New and Folder, then rename it anything you like. (i.e. Trash Bin)
3. Drag & drop the Recycle Bin on the new Folder to create a shortcut.
4. Save the new Folder (containing Recycle Bin shortcut) to the directory of your choice (i.e. C:\Trash Bin) by dragging and dropping.
5. UnLock the taskbar.
6. Right-click on the taskbar and select Toolbar and New toolbar...
7. Navigate to the location you saved the New Folder (Ex: Trash Bin), select it and click on the Select Folder button.
8. This places the new Toolbar and a Separator (dotted lines) on the taskbar.
9. Right click on the Separator and uncheck Show Text and Show Title.
10. Right click on the Separator and select View and Large Icons.
11. You now have the Recycle Bin pinned to the taskbar.
    You can even right click on it and choose "Empty Recycle Bin".
12. You can now remove it from the desktop.

The article goes on to explain how to place the Recycle Bin on right side or left side of the Taskbar.

Comment: Well, I looked at the question today and started to type an answer, but you have already typed it. +1 and hope OP will accept the answer.

Comment: Followed your instructions step by step and the recycle bin now sits nicely on the taskbar. Thanks a million! +50

Answer (score 5):

To remove it from the desktop in Win7 (so I presume Win8 aswell), you can do this

```
Right click Desktop -> Personalise -> Change Desktop Items -> Untick Recycle Bin
```

You can also follow this guide to put into the taskbar.

http://www.techspot.com/guides/196-recycle-bin-on-windows-7-taskbar/

Comment: Ought to summarise the guide here instead of only posting a link.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can remove recycle bin icon from the desktop as "Bali C" has suggested (Confirmed).
2. Moreover you can move it to the Start Menu (Not to the task bar) by...

   `Right click on "Recycle Bin Icon", select "Pin to Start"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, should you wish not to have any icon on your desktop at all then right-click on the desktop, go to "View" and untick "Show desktop icons".

You can still get to these icons (including the recycle bin) by opening the desktop shortcut in the Windows Explorer (it's pinned as a favourite by default).

Answer (score 1):

Pin Recycle Bin to File Explorer jump list:

1. Drag Recycle Bin icon to File Explorer icon pinned on the Taskbar.
   The tooltip will display: Pin to File Explorer.
2. Access it by right-clicking File Explorer icon and then clicking Recycle Bin.

Another way to pin Recycle Bin to Taskbar:

1. Create a new shortcut in any folder you like: Right-click the empty space, point to **New** and click **Shortcut**.
2. Type `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:RecycleBinFolder` into the **Location of the item** field. Click **Next**.
3. Type the name of the shortcut: `Recycle Bin`. Click **Finish**.
4. Now change the icon of the shortcut:

   1. Right-click the shortcut and then click **Properties**.
   2. Click **Change icon**.
   3. Type `%windir%\System32\shell32.dll` into **Look for icons in this file** field and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to display the icons.
   4. Select Recycle Bin icon: it's at row 4 and column 8.
      Click the right arrow of the scroll bar and you will see the Recycle Bin icon at the bottom right corner.
   5. Click **OK** twice to close Change Icon and Properties dialogs.
5. Now drag the icon to the Taskbar to pin it, or right-click it and then click **Pin to Taskbar**.
6. Hide Recycle Bin icon on the Desktop:

   1. Right-click the desktop and then click **Personalize**.
   2. Click **Change desktop icons** on the left pane of the Personalization window.
   3. Clear **Recycle Bin** check box, and click **OK** to confirm.

      And of course, you can pin Recycle Bin to the Start screen by right-clicking its icon on the desktop and then clicking **Pin to Start**.

Comment: It will just open the recycle bin as Explorer, not like the OP want to.